# Giving JmenuItems loaded from a text file an action

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm loading JmenuItems from a text file using this code

```
FileInputStream wordsFile = new FileInputStream(signlink.findcachedir() + "/Playlist.div");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(wordsFile));
        String[] favoriteSongs = new String[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < favoriteSongs.length; i++) {
            favoriteSongs[i] = br.readLine();
            if (favoriteSongs[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(favoriteSongs[i]);
                JMenuItem song = new JMenuItem(favoriteSongs[i]);
                song.addActionListener(this);
                favorites.add(favoriteSongs[i]);
            } else { 
                wordsFile.close();
                break;
            }
        }
```

How do I add actions for the JmenuItems

Comment: You're already adding an `ActionListener` from your current class

Comment: And how would I give the menu items actions from the ActionListener

Comment: You could specify the action command of each menu item, allowing to better identify the action which the user has just selected

Comment: It doesn't seem to be recognizing any of the buttons being pressed

Comment: I know this is a month old but if you havent figured it out, could you update your question with some more of your code? As of now, we dont know what you action listener looks like and I dont see anywhere where your new menu items are being added to a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand you correctly but:
You added action listner 'song.addActionListener(this)' so this mean that you have in your class an overriden method from interface, you need to put some logic there and it should work i.e.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
    String song = item.getText();
    listOfSth.add(song);
}
```

Or you could create new class that implements ActionListner and add it to created MenuItem

```
    JMenuItem l = new JMenuItem();
    l.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
```